# Any open source tools to integrate ServiceNow and VSTS

Tags: azure-devops, servicenow

I am looking for some open source or free tools to integrate Service Now and VSTS?

is there any such tools available. please suggest.

Thanks.

Comment: What are you trying to integrate? Is it just Git source control for a Studio application?

Answer (score 0):

Integrate them through REST API:

[REST API Overview for Visual Studio Team Services and Team Foundation Server](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/overview)

[ServiceNow REST API](https://docs.servicenow.com/bundle/istanbul-servicenow-platform/page/integrate/inbound-rest/concept/c_RESTAPI.html)

There are some articles about integrating them:

[Integrating ServiceNow and Visual Studio Team Services using Stamplay](https://medium.com/@niegrejoh/integrating-servicenow-and-visual-studio-team-services-draft-1e9840f0fb06)

[Visual Studio Team Services Integration](https://community.servicenow.com/thread/235155)